# Isn't this code incorrect?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, copy, memcpy

My instructor presents this [slide](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IS1500/2012/forel/2012-ce-f5.pdf) for "matrix copying":

```
#define ROWSIZ 17
#define COLSIZ 27
int enamatrisen[ROWSIZ][COLSIZ];
int andramatrisen[ROWSIZ][COLSIZ];

void matcpy (int* dst, int* src)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<ROWSIZ, i=i+1)   /* rad-nr */
   for (j=0; j<COLSIZ, j=j+1)  /* kolumn-nr */
    dst[i][j] = src[i][j];
}
```

But

1) There're bugs where it says `,` it should be `;`
and

2) The code doesn't compile. gcc complains about pointer being used as arrays or similar. What is correct code? How is this effort close? Shouldn't memcpy be used for this instead or is this an effort to implement something like memcpy?

Comment: FWIW, while weird, I believe the "," will have the 'correct' effect here.

Comment: it is "for( ; ; )" not "for ( ; , )", so GCC is right with complaining about commas.

Comment: Yes, but inserting the comma, you can still get a functioning loop, however, you will end up with an infinite loop, as the evaluation of a comma will simply be the last thing in the sequence...  You would need extra code in the body to get out of it.  Still worth mentioning, I believe.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski Utter nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function parameters are defined wrong.

More info on passing multi-dimentional arrays:
http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html

Also, comma in the `for` loop should be a semi-colon.

```
void matcpy(int dst[][COLSIZ], int src[][COLSIZ])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ROWSIZ; i = i + 1)   /* rad-nr */
        for (j = 0; j < COLSIZ; j = j + 1)  /* kolumn-nr */
            dst[i][j] = src[i][j];
}
```

or

```
void matcpy(int (*dst)[COLSIZ], int (*src)[COLSIZ])
{ 
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ROWSIZ; i = i + 1)   /* rad-nr */
       for (j = 0; j < COLSIZ; j = j + 1)  /* kolumn-nr */
           dst[i][j] = src[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Very nice, if only I also could pass `COLSIZE` as a parameter for copying matrices that are local variables. I hope you understand my little problem now since the spec says that the function parameters should be pointer to array, pointer to array, int colsize, int rowsize for copying matrices of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is incorrect.

You need:

```
int matcpy( int (*dst)[ COLSIZ ], int (*src)[ COLSIZ ]
```

or

```
void matcpy(int dst[][ COLSIZ ], int src[][ COLSIZ ])
```

---

`memcpy` may be used, but as this is an exercise, maybe the point is to see how to iterate over 2D array and how to access its elements.

---

In the `for` loops, the `,` *must* be `;`. The other answers/comments are right - you may use comma in expressions and you may only add `;` in the `for`, for example:

```
//------------------------v
for (i=0; i<ROWSIZ, i=i+1 ; )
```

but this will be undefined behavior, because:

- the condition `i<ROWSIZ, i=i+1` will be true as long as `i != 0` - the evaluation of a comma operator is the last value in the sequence
- as `i` is `int`, the overflow will cause undefined behavior

In other words, you'll probably end up with endless loop.

Comment: Let me guess why. You insist that the OP must pass in pointers to pointers. That's not going to work with 2d arrays he defined in the main program. What needs to be passed in is pointers to 1d arrays (`int (*)[COLSIZ]`), as shown in another answer.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - ah, right. That's something else now. Thanks for the remark, edited.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work because your function declaration is :

```
void matcpy (int* dst, int* src)
```

and in the return is :

```
return dst[i][j] = src[i][j]
```

you should change your function declaration to :

```
void matcpy (int** dst, int** src)
```

Comment: wrong, pointers to pointers  and pointers to arrays are not the same thing